# Поиск в базе по букве (как в Google Play)

Tags: actionbar, android, sqlite

Всем привет!
Пишу приложение для `Android`. Использую библиотеку `android-support-v7-appcompat`, чтоб поддерживались и старые версии. Вопрос такой - как сделать поиск, например, как в `Google Play`, чтоб при вводе текста например буква А выводилось все содержимое из базы начинающее на букву А в виде выпадающего списка. Запрос к примеру

```
Strinq query='SELECT * from TABLE WHERE name LIKE 'A%';'
```

Comment: запросс составлен правильно, в чем проблема? не совсем понятно...    
Если в экранировании кавычек, то гуглите, собственно на тему экранирования кавычек...

Comment: Да нет, с запросом то все в порядке. Я не знаю как все это вывести в виде выпадающего списка, когда нужно что-то найти.

Answer (score 1):

В документации есть кое-что про реализацию поиска, загляните если не видели ранее: [Add search interface to action bar](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) и [Store data for searching](http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html) из той же серии. Думаю эти два дока должны Вам помочь в реализации общей механики в верном направлении.

Можно сделать примерно так(свое велосипедное): в ActionBar добавляете свою вью(EditText, а ниже Spinner c android:spinnerMode="dialog", ListView, etc), ставите на него TextWatcher, внутри него переопределяете onTextChanged(), парсите строку, которую он возвращает - шлете запрос в БД - ставите адаптер в выпадающий список. Всю работу с БД делать в Loader-e, например CursorLoader или свой кастомный.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в сторону `AutoCompeteTextView` - надо к нему привязывать адаптер (в данном случае `CursorAdapter` поверх вашего запроса.

Там есть одна засада - эта штука не совсем верно будет работать для нелатинских символов, в том смысле что `like` от SQLite неверно отрабатывает case-insensitive поиск с не ASCII набором ([см. документацию](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html))